# With django-rest-framework how do I assign a field to the request user when using a ModelViewSet?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions#associating-snippets-with-users) recommends for APIViews:

```
def pre_save(self, obj):
    obj.owner = self.request.user
```

This doesn't seem to work as I get back:

```js
{
    "owner": [
        "This field cannot be null."
    ]
}
```

edit:  The pre_save method never gets called.  Checked by inserting a call to `pdb` in the `pre_save` method.

My serializer is a plain HyperlinkedModelSerializer with the model and list of fields specified in Meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my model I had overridden `clean_fields`.  The signature for `clean_fields`:

```
Model.clean_fields(exclude=None)
```

My custom `clean_fields`:

```
def clean_fields(self, exclude=None):
    super(Applicant, self).clean_fields()  # Bug here.  
    # custom clean_fields code
```

I didn't pass the `exclude` parameter to the super class!

Oh god this took me so many hours to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Check [DRF 3.0 release notes](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#generic-views) docs. They have an example doing exactly what you need with `perform_create()` in ViewSet .

Answer (score 0):

Include the "owner" field in the serializer `Meta.exclude` (or just remove it from the field list if you are using the "positive" list).

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta(object):
        model: Foo
        exclude: ('owner',)
```

This way you will not trigger validation for this field. Also, make sure the endpoint is decorated with mandatory authentication or check if `self.request.user.is_authenticated()` is `True`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  As far as I can tell, using `exclude` is the same as using `fields` with `owner` not included.  Also, edited question text with more information about `pre_save`.

Comment: Works for me. Can't help without trying to reproduce the problem. Please update the question with minimum sample code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Problem fixed by upgrading from 2.3.13 to 2.4.3.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Not fixed.  Upgrading to 2.4.3 triggered another bug which hid this issue.  Working on a simplified test case now...

Comment: Fixed problem.  See my answer to make fun of me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the validation fails because the "owner" field is required but not given a value in the initial data(it gets a value after validation). Because serializer.is_valid() is run before pre_save() then it fails.

Why the version change fixes it I have no idea. I myself have set owner as required=False although an object always will get one from pre_save()

Comment: Yes, this is exactly it.  I traced through it with a debugger and found this to be the issue.  I still can't figure out how to get around it.  Upgrading DRF raised another bug which hid this issue.  Now that I've fixed that bug this issue has reappeared.  Working on implementing a simplified test case now...

Comment: You might want to set owner field in the Model as null/blank=False. If you always set it in the pre_save() it should never get a null value even if it's allowed

Comment: Fixed problem.  See my answer.